# Calling C# executable from perl script

Tags: perl, c#-4.0, activeperl

I am trying to execute a C# 4.0 console application from a perl script and trying to capture the output of the application. The C# application is a multithreaded application but it is writing the output to the console using the normal Console.WriteLine() function.

To fetch the output I am using the `` method in perl as :

```
my @commands = `app.exe param1 param2`
```

But when I am running the script I am getting error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid.

   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.Console.SetCursorPosition(Int32 left, Int32 top)
   at Netapp.CmDownload.Processor.DownloadProcessor.Start(String[] args)
   at Netapp.CmDownload.CmDownload.Main(String[] args)
```

terminating the application.

Note: C# application is a 64bit app running on .Net Framework 4.0
      I have tried running the script using active perl 64bit as well as 32 bit version with no effect.

Comment: `System.Console.SetCursorPosition` – aha, so it isn't simply printing to standard output, but drawing more complex output onto the terminal! Capturing the output won't do, you'll need a terminal emulator and a way to interpret the output as the output isn't simply sequential.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your application is trying to use the console in a relatively advanced way - setting the cursor position. In this case, you don't really *have* a console, you just have piped output... so there's no console handle, and `SetCursorPosition` is failing.

See if there's any command line option to turn off the advanced console handling. (If it's your own app, add one :)